# Keep Timer Ticking in Background

Tags: android, timer, background, count, countdowntimer

How can I keep the value of my timer resuming after going to another activity , my problem is that it's set to default if I switched to another activity I thought of using `sharedpreference` but it won't help because I need it to keep decrementing in the background.

```
    public void reset()
    {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    private void setTimer() {
        int time = 5;
        if(countDownTimer==null)
        {               
            totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            reset();
            totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;                
        }
    }

    private void startTimer() {         

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
            // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
            // milliseconds

            //@Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

                textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
                // format the textview to show the easily readable format
            } 

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                textViewShowTime.setText("Time up!");
                textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: to run code in background use a `Service`

Answer (score 1):

You should stop your `CountDownTimer` in `onPause` and restart in `onResume`, your `textViewShowTime` might not be valid while your activity is in background.

If you need to call some code every 500ms no matter what activity you are in, then consider using `AlarmManager`.